# SonarQube issue for method from static resource

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

There is a static resource in the org like below:

myStaticResource.js

```
(function() {

    function someMethod(eventData, cmp)  {
        //Do something
    }
    window.someMethod = someMethod;
})();
```

I am using the resource like below in my LWC js:

```
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import myStaticResourceLibrary from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myStaticResource';

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement {
  
  connectedCallback() {
    loadScript(this, myStaticResourceLibrary)
        .then(() =>{
                    someMethod(eventData, this);
                   })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
          });
    }
}
```

My functionality is working fine.
I pushed my code to *git* and *SonarQube* started running.
*SonarQube* is showing below issue for this code:

**Variables should be defined before being usedjavascript:S3827
"someMethod" does not exist. Change its name or declare it so that its usage doesn't result in a "ReferenceError".**

I tried using this before calling the method.
What should be the recommended way to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube can't detect the symbol because of how it is loaded. If you want to make SonarQube to recognize the function, use the global object `window`:

```
window.someMethod(eventData, this);
```

There's also mention that you can set the `sonar.javascript.globals` project variable, mentioned in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42268346).

Comment: I used window.someMethod(eventData, this); and the issue is resolved.